# Efficient interaction with canvas and ImageData from .NET WebAssembly

Tags: .net-core, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I would like to receive image data in .NET WebAssembly and then paint it on an html5 canvas element.

I found a Rust example that interacts with canvas and renders image data through its `web_sys` interop library: https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/julia.html

The interesting part is that Rust has transparent access to html5 `ImageData` and `CanvasRenderingContext2d` objects.

Relevant source code:

**index.js**

```
import('./pkg')
    .then(wasm => {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');        
        wasm.draw(ctx, 600, 600);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

**lib.rs**

```
use web_sys::{CanvasRenderingContext2d, ImageData};

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn draw(
    ctx: &CanvasRenderingContext2d,
    width: u32,
    height: u32
) -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    let mut data = somefunction(width, height);
    let data = ImageData::new_with_u8_clamped_array_and_sh(Clamped(&mut data), width, height)?;
    ctx.put_image_data(&data, 0.0, 0.0)
}
```

What would be the corresponding Blazor .NET WebAssembly?

The workaround I have implemented uses json serializion that is part of .NET JSInterop implementation in order to pass a byte array from .NET WebAssembly into JavaScript. This results in a mime64 encoded string at the JavaScript side which then must be decoded first before it can be transformed into an ImageData object.

Relevant code:

**MyComponent.razor.cs**

```
public partial class MyComponent : ComponentBase
{
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
       var bytearray = somefunction(600, 600);
       await jSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("draw", 600, 600, bytearray);
   }
}
```

**blazorcanvasinterop.ts**

```
draw(xw: number, yw: number, pixelsbase64: string): void {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');        
    const pixels = base64ToArrayBuffer(pixelsbase64); // some mime64 decoder function
    const imageData = ctx.createImageData(xw, yw);
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

This is obviously not very performant. It creates multiple copies of the byte array:

In .NET:

1. The original `bytearray` byte array in .NET

In JavaScript:

2. The mime64 encoded `pixelsbase64` string
3. The `pixels` byte array
4. The `imageData` ImageData object

Answer (score 3):

Look technique from this repo https://github.com/alexandrelozano/BlazorVoxelSpace or this https://github.com/EngstromJimmy/ZXSpectrum

Resume:

In CSharp:

```
protected void Flip()
        {
            var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(screen, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            var pinned = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            var mono = JSRuntime as WebAssemblyJSRuntime;
            mono.InvokeUnmarshalled<IntPtr, string>("PaintCanvas", pinned);
            gch.Free();
        }
```

And in JS:

```
window.PaintCanvas = function PaintCanvas(dataPtr) {
                imageData.data.set(Uint8ClampedArray.from(Module.HEAPU8.subarray(dataPtr, dataPtr + imageData.data.length)));
                context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
                context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                return true;
            }
```